# BT136 inner resistance

Tags: resistance, triac

I found two datasheets for the BT136 triac:

[Datasheet one](http://www.radiotechnika.hu/images/BT136E.pdf)

[Datasheet two](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/BT136-600E-352978.pdf)

But those datasheets didn't mention the inner resistance of the triac (or I couldn't find it.)

What's the resistance between pin T1 and T2 of BT136 triac when the gate is activated?

**Edit:**

I found another [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1758173.pdf) which mentioned the resistance:
[image]

If I pull 2 A from the BT136 what the resistance will be? how to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is this: -

[image]

On-resistance isn't quoted for triacs because they are highly non-linear when \$V_T\$ drops to around a volt or so (unlike MOSFETs in their "ohmic" region).

Comment: Thanks, please take a look at the edit.

Comment: 2 amps at 25 degC will mean a typical forward drop of about 1.4 volts. So you have 1.4 volts and 2 amps - this is equivalent to a resistor of 0.7 ohms. But, at 4 amps the drop will be 1.6 volts hence the equivalent resistance is 0.4 ohms - do you see why manufacturer's don't specify resistance and prefer to show the graph instead?

Comment: A better question /answer is **What does Vo, Rs mean?**  which is on every datasheet. This graph duplicates what is in  the question.

Comment: Why don't you ask it then: and you can supply this answer: Vo is the intercept on the x axis and Ro is the slope. @Tony the graph was in my answer before the OP altered their question to include his own version (note they are different).

Comment: that answer is not what I meant.

Comment: OK I thought you were being "playful" LOL @Tony

Comment: I was , but then I am thinking, why do they say so little about Vo, Rs and why is this the real answer

Comment: Rs is the "ON resistance " reported except this is incremental above Vo (offset)

Answer (score 1):

> What's the resistance between pin T1 and T2 of BT136 Triac when the gate is activated?

You cannot predict current by a linear resistance , but you can using the incremental series resistance Rs, just as you can with any Zener, LED diode,  Switching transistor , SCR and Triac.

For the Triac the equation with the variables shown in every VI graph are;
$$V_T= V_O+I*R_S$$

The Vo, Rs are defined  to interpolate  power dissipation at Tj=125'C $$P_d=V_O*I+I^2R_S$$

Some Triacs may have higher Vo but half the Rs value for almost twice the Amp rated Triacs.

The identical value given in every datasheet linked in your question (since they are the same Part Number) indicated to conform to the worst case specifications for this part number.
[image]

*I measured this RED slope by counting pixels to obtain ΔV=0.91V / 10A then found that it matched the slope at 125'C*

**Other info**

The semiconductor industry is inconsistent if/when & how they report these linear regression terms, but this characteristic exists for every semiconductor.

- for example Diodes Inc and TI/(nee Fairchild) have superbeta power BJT switches with very low Vce(sat) and **Rce values** which is equivalent to a Triac's Vo & Rs values except a Triac has 2 transistors in series (Vbe+Vce) for each thyristor so the voltage drop is similar to a Darlington used as a switch.
- All Zeners have an incremental Zener resistance above Threshold **Zzt** @ Izt such  that Vz= Vzt + Izt*Zzt  = nominal Zener Voltage at rated current above threshold Vzt

Vo depends on the emission coefficient for all diodes. This is turn depends on the semi. material and dopants for Si, Ge, AlGaAs, GaP, etc. and even reverse diode Zener voltage.

White LEDs are the same, but they never report these parameters, but you can extract them by linear interpolation of the typical curves. The reason is probably due to user errors with unknown heatsinks  and Tj rise, so they are always graphed 25'C or 85'C or guaranteed in the table values for Vf @ If.

Comment: Really informative, thank you.